# Syntax error for an SQL query in a WCF service

Tags: mysql, sql, wcf

I get a syntax error when I try to give table name as a parameter like this:

```
[WebGet]
public List<callersW> GetCallersByCallerIdF(string callerid, string table)
{
    testCDREntities1 context = this.CurrentDataSource;

    List<callersW> result = context.Database.SqlQuery<callersW>("SELECT CallerId,CalledID,Created, " + 
        " Answered,Destroyed,DisconnectionCode,RTP_Caller_G107MOS,RTP_Caller_LostPackets, " +
        " RTP_Caller_MaxRfc3550Jitter,RTP_Caller_MeanRfc3550Jitter,RTP_Called_G107MOS, " +
        " RTP_Called_LostPackets,RTP_Called_MaxRfc3550Jitter,RTP_Called_MeanRfc3550Jitter FROM '"+table+"' where CallerId = '"+ callerid +"'").ToList();
    return result;
}
```

But if I give it inline then it works fine:

```
[WebGet]
public List<callersW> GetCallersByCallerIdF(string callerid)
{
    testCDREntities1 context = this.CurrentDataSource;

    List<callersW> result = context.Database.SqlQuery<callersW>("SELECT CallerId,CalledID,Created, " + 
        " Answered,Destroyed,DisconnectionCode,RTP_Caller_G107MOS,RTP_Caller_LostPackets, " +
        " RTP_Caller_MaxRfc3550Jitter,RTP_Caller_MeanRfc3550Jitter,RTP_Called_G107MOS, " +
        " RTP_Called_LostPackets,RTP_Called_MaxRfc3550Jitter,RTP_Called_MeanRfc3550Jitter FROM TestTable where CallerId = '"+ callerid +"'").ToList();
    return result;
}
```

and this is the error:

```
An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Incorrect syntax near 'TestTable'.
```

Comment: Looks like you accidentally created two accounts. You can [contact the team](http://stackoverflow.com/contact) to have them merged, which will allow you to regain direct editing privileges on your contributions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to quote the table name - in your example the table name is specified as `TestTable` in the second example but it comes out to `'TestTable'` in the first example. Table names shouldn't be surrounded by quotes.

If you're using a reserved keyword as a table name, then you should surround the table name with backticks, for example:

```
`TestTable`
```

Note that it's **not** the single quote character.

See the documentation - [9.2 Schema object names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html)